# Tem como fazer um SELECT retornando a quantidade e o nome de cada cor?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou fazendo essas duas consultas pra baixar as cores e a quantidade de cada cor na tabela `bike`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT color FROM bike ORDER BY color ASC
SELECT COUNT(color) FROM bike GROUP BY color ORDER BY color ASC
```

Como eu faço para que na segunda consulta, as contagens venham também com o nome da cor associada, em um array só?

Comment: Qual o banco de dados que você está usando? SQLite? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de tabela `bike`, com conteúdo, e explicar o objeto que você queria que chegasse no seu código PHP?

Comment: mysql, bike tem varias informações e uma 10 colunas  e a coluna que eu quero e color, preciso que retorne tudo em 1 array, vou por o que retorna.

Comment: Porque a sua primeira consulta não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: porque preciso usar ambas num foreach exibindo assim, cor(qtd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `GROUP BY` já garante que só vai ter uma de cada color na saída — basta puxar as duas colunas ao mesmo tempo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantidade,
       color
FROM bike
GROUP BY color
ORDER BY color
```

Comment: ah, hue assim que puxa '-', valeu vou testar aqui.

Comment: pensei que não teria como puxar outro valor junto com qtd e estava procurando alguma forma, mas nem notei que segue a mesma regra caso chamasse outro campo da tabela.

Comment: Um detalhe importante é que você só pode puxar campos “nus” (sem estarem dentro de um COUNT(), SUM(), MAX(), …) se eles estiverem listados no GROUP BY (mas isso não é problema nesse caso).